# UIToolbar tintColor not having an effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uicolor

I have a timezone picker that's showing a different color for the "Done" button between an iPhone and iPod:

**iPhone**:

[image]

**iPod**:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 44)];
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor darkAppColor];
    toolbar.translucent = NO;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:nil];

    // doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // this has no effect
    // toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // this has no effect

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    toolbar.items = @[flexibleSpace, doneButton];
```

**AppConstants.m**

```
@implementation UIColor
    ...
    + (UIColor *)darkAppColor
    {
                return [UIColor colorWithHex:0x054e85];
    }
    ...
@end
```

I'd like for the iPod screen to look like that of the iPhone (without the light blue "Done" button).  What's weird is that if I change this line:

```
toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor darkAppColor];
```

to

```
toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Then, the entire nav bar of the picker (including the "Done" button) is uniform (though the wrong color).  As you can see from the commented out lines in the code above, I've also tried changing the tintColor property of the "Done" button as well as the toolbar but that seems to have no effect at all.

Both devices are running iOS 10.2.

Can somebody tell me:

1. Why does iPhone and iPod handle this code differently?
2. Why is setting the tintColor property of "toolbar" and "doneButton" not having any effect?
3. How can I get the iPod display to match the iPhone?

Comment: Try setting toolbar barStyle to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent.     **[toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];**

Comment: No effect.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Remove bar style and check it